# Private user file uploads with nodejs

Tags: node.js

In my nodejs application I want to implement a filesharing feature without any third party file hosting service. The goal is that a user can upload a file to a secured folder. After that only the user that uploaded the file and other permitted users can access the file. The file should not be readable or accessible from the public.

How do I secure a folder inside my nodejs application so only authenticated and permitted users can access this folder?

This is what I came up with:

- create a folder `/private-uploads`
- create a REST controller that receives a filename or file id
- check for a valid authentication and permission inside the controller
- return the file found by the filename or file id

the project structure would be something like this now:

```
- /node_modules
- /private-uploads  (contains files that should not be reachable as a non authenticated user)
- ...some other folders...
- package.json
- server.js  (contains the REST controllers to upload and get files from the /private-uploads folder)
```

This idea seems so simple that I am concerned if there is any security issue with this example above.

Am I missing out on any security aspects with this solution? Is this vulnerable to path traversal or something like that?

So I am wondering if there is any way to get the contents of the `/private-uploads` folder in a nodejs application as a not authenticated user/guest?

Answer (score -2):

The question what package you want to use for the `file-upload-process` must of the package is used for this upgradation from node.js is multer also see the formidable
and secure this with your authenticated middleware

Comment: This does not answer my question: Is there any way to get the contents of the /private-uploads folder as a not authenticated user like in my described case?